# Unable to cast object of type 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteDataParameter' to type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'

Tags: oracle, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using this code

```
using (var db = OpenDbConnection())
            if (db != null)
                db.Run(dbCnx =>
                {
                    var trans = dbCnx.BeginTransaction();

                        dbCnx.UpdateOnly(new ProtectiveMarkingRequest
                        {
                            SecondApproverUserName = request.SecondApproverUserName,
                            Status = request.Status
                        },
                            onlyFields: p => new
                            {
                                p.SecondApproverUserName,
                                p.Status
                            },
                            @where: p => p.WorkItemCode == request.WorkItemCode);
                    } 

                    trans.Commit();
                });
```

After updating to servicestack.ormlite.oracle 4.0.52 (from 4.0.38) I receive the following error:

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteDataParameter' to type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'.
  Source=Oracle.DataAccess
  StackTrace:
       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection.Add(Object obj)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.DbDataParameterExtensions.AddParam(IOrmLiteDialectProvider dialectProvider, IDbCommand dbCmd, Object value, Type fieldType)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle.OracleOrmLiteDialectProvider.PrepareUpdateRowStatement(IDbCommand dbCmd, Object objWithProperties, ICollection`1 updateFields)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.WriteExpressionCommandExtensions.UpdateOnlySql[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, T model, SqlExpression`1 onlyFields)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.WriteExpressionCommandExtensions.UpdateOnly[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, T model, SqlExpression`1 onlyFields)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteExpressionsApi.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.b__6(IDbCommand dbCmd)
       at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter)
       at ECMAPI.Repository.Security.SecurityRepository.<>c__DisplayClassfb.b__f9(IDbConnection dbCnx) in SecurityRepository.cs:line 1970

Any clues?

Comment: The API to open a transaction in OrmLite is OpenTransaction(), I'd also remove dB.Run()

Comment: @mythz can you please give me an example of this?

Comment: I've added an answer with a rewritten example.

Answer (score 1):

To use [Transaction Support in OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#transaction-support) you should use `OpenTransaction()` also the `Run()` extension method doesn't provide any value so I'd rewrite your example to just:

```
using (var db = OpenDbConnection())
using (var trans = db.OpenTransaction())
{
    db.UpdateOnly(new ProtectiveMarkingRequest
        {
            SecondApproverUserName = request.SecondApproverUserName,
            Status = request.Status
        },
        onlyFields: p => new {
            p.SecondApproverUserName,
            p.Status
        },
        @where: p => p.WorkItemCode == request.WorkItemCode);
    } 
    trans.Commit();
}
```

Comment: @NicolasI Looks like this [issue was resolved in v4.0.54](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/285b3b95359f4c170e344e0471429b7f1677ceb8) - please upgrade to v4.0.54 or preferably the latest v4.0.56.